# In JavaScript, override root text of console.dir(myObj)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an class, `FriendlyStack`, used for debugging that has a message and a stack trace.  I use it primarily for detecting race conditions.  When `console.dir` is called on an instance of my class, I want the root node's text to display the message.

My function name is `gotHere()` and it calls `console.dir` on an instance of `FriendlyStack`.

```
// debugging helper function
function gotHere(msg) {
    console.dir(new FriendlyStack(msg));
}

class FriendlyStack {
    constructor(msg) {
        this.msg = msg;

        // new Error().stack gets the string of the stack trace
        // .split('\n') creates an array of each line of the stack trace
        // .slice(3) removes the first three lines, which are:
        //    Error
        //       at new FriendlyStack (...)
        //       at gotHere (...)
        this.stack = new Error().stack.split('\n').slice(3);
    }

    // some override to make console.dir display this.msg as the root node
    // instead of FriendlyStack
}
```

For most classes/objects, when you call `console.dir` the root of the tree displayed is the name of the prototype of the object.

```
console.dir({foo: 'bar'})
v Object
    foo: "bar"
  > __proto__: Object

console.dir([1, 2, 3])
v Array[3]
   0: 1
   1: 2
   2: 3
   length: 3
 > __proto__: Array[0]
```

However, when you call it on a string or number, the displayed root is the value.

```
console.dir(1)
> 1

console.dir('foobar')
> foobar
```

I would have expected, given the behavior of calling `console.dir(someObject)`, that `console.dir(1)` would have displayed `Number` as the root node.  This different behavior suggests there might a way to change what's printed as the root node, but it also could just be that primitives are special cases.

Is there a way to achieve my desired behavior?  I tried overloading `FriendlyStack.toString`, but that did not work.

Comment: Would it be accurate to phrase your desired behavior as 'have console.dir() display the primitive data type of the logged data'?

Comment: @barry-johnson I'm not certain.  I want the console to display the interactive tree structure that `console.dir` does, so that when I expand the root node, I see the stack array.  I'm not sure if `console.log` has this behavior.

Comment: I updated my comment, `console.log` was a muscle-memory typo.

Comment: I'm still uncertain what you mean.  If I understand correctly, the primitive data type would be `[Object object]`, right?

Comment: The thing is, `console.dir` is specifically focused on Javascript objects which have a deeper structure. The primitives do not. Particularly given that console.dir is a non-standard (and not even standards-track) thing, this might be challenging to maintain over time as well.

Comment: In JS there are five primitive types: null, undefined, number, string, boolean. Everything else is an Object. `[Object object]` is just a fairly useless string casting.

Comment: Makes sense.  So I guess what I'm asking is if we can indicate to `console.dir` to make the root node use the behavior of `console.dir(s.msg)` and the child nodes use the default behavior.

Comment: It would not appear to. Do you want the message to be updated interactively as well? I guess I am really confused about what would be the purposes of a dynamically updating stack trace, which is basically a dump of facts about the past (i.e. not subject to future change). Or why wouldn't you just emit your message with a console.log before your `console.dir` call.

Comment: I don't need it to dynamically update anything.  The stack isn't going to change after `gotHere()` has been called.  But you make a good point.  I should just `console.log(msg)` and then `console.dir(myStack)`.  It avoids over-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log a string instead of an object, use a function that returns one (instead of creating an instance):

```
function gotHere(msg) {
    console.dir(friendlyStack(msg));
}

function friendlyStack(msg) {
    // new Error().stack gets the string of the stack trace
    // .split('\n') creates an array of each line of the stack trace
    // .slice(3) removes the first three lines, which are:
    //    Error
    //       at new FriendlyStack (...)
    //       at gotHere (...)
    const stack = new Error().stack.split('\n').slice(3);

    return msg + "\n" + stack;
}
```

Comment: This was actually what I had originally.  I didn't like the clutter in the log, though, since the strings are so long.  I want one line per item that I can expand to see the stack details.

Comment: No, you can't do that, there's no control over the formatting of logged values. You might try something like `console.log(msg, new Stack())` though